# Can't see close img or other attributes in LIghtbox2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox2

I can't see close img or other attributes in Lightbox2.

It does open a larger image in Firefox but the only controls are the back arrow in browser.

When I make changes to CSS they do not show up.

Comment: Don't link to a site which exhibits the behavior. Once it's fixed or the site goes down, this question becomes useless to future people with the same problem. Create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that code in your question.

Comment: I have figured it out!  I had to put the java script into the table body that my images where in and not overall body of page.  This made everything work.